# How to parse this Json structure in Java

Tags: java, json

I have the following Json structure:

```
{
    "Response": ["2014", "2015"],
    "Error": false,
    "ErrorDetails": null
}
```

How can I parse the value inside response?

I usually use this code:

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Response");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString(???);
    ......
}
```

But I can't use `getString` in this case

Comment: Why do you call `arr.getJSONObject` ? You can call `arr.getString(i)` directly: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: @user3707125 yeah, that's correct thank you! If you post it as answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [arr.getString(i)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString%28int%29) directly.